# Reading a line from a text file, splitting the string version of that line into two parts

Tags: ruby, string, split, slice

Newbie learning Ruby.

I am trying to take a txt file and on each line take the first 3 characters and assign them as a key, and the rest of the string as that's keys value.

```
f = File.open("textfile.txt", "r")
finalHash = {"Key" => "Data"}
lineString = ""


while f.gets != nil do
  lineString = f.gets
  part1 = lineString.slice(0, 2)
  part2 = lineString.slice(3, lineString.length)
  finalHash[:part1] = part2
end

puts finalHash
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: how big is this file of yours? Must be a big fella

Comment: Nope it's small - your solution worked thanks!

Comment: If you want the value of the variable `part1` to be the hash key, use `finalHash[part1]`, not `finalHash[:part1]`. `:part1` is a Symbol, which is a special kind of string, so the latter would result in a hash with exactly one key, `:part1`.

Comment: Also, you're doing `f.gets` twice in every iteration: once on the `while` line and once on the following line, so you're basically skipping every other line. Don't do `while f.gets != nil`, do `while lineString = f.gets`. No need to explicitly check for `nil`, as `nil` is falsey and iteration will stop as soon as `f.gets` returns `nil`. Lastly, don't forget to close your file.

Comment: thanks Jordan! so to be clear by calling f.gets twice I'm essentially skipping lines?

Answer (score 1):

the 2nd parameter of slice is the length, not the end-index, so change:

```
part1 = lineString.slice(0, 2)
```

to:

```
part1 = lineString.slice(0, 3)
```

> If passed a start index and a length, returns a substring containing
>   length characters starting at the index

Also you don't need the second parameter here (this is not a bug though):

```
part2 = lineString.slice(3, lineString.length)
```

This is enough:

```
part2 = lineString.slice(3)
```

Comment: Thank you I should've know that! Question though - does the .gets method I'm using return a string?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create a file:

```
text = <<_
Now is the
time for all
good Rubiests
to come to the
aid of their
bowling team.
_

FName = 'temp'

File.write(FName, text)
  #=> 80
```

Now read the file a line at a time and construct the desired hash:

```
File.foreach(FName).with_object({}) do |line, h|
  h[line.slice!(0,3)] = line.chomp
end
  #=> {"Now"=>" is the", "tim"=>"e for all", "goo"=>"d Rubiests",
  #    "to "=>"come to the", "aid"=>" of their", "bow"=>"ling team."}
```

After reading the first line,

```
h = { "Now"=>" is the" }

line = "time for all\n"

a = line.chomp
  #=> "time for all"
b = a.slice!(0,3)
  #=> "tim"
a #=> "e for all" 
h[b] = a
  #=> "e for all" 
h #=> {"Now"=>" is the", "tim"=>"e for all"}
```

No direction is given if a line contains fewer than three characters. That may be something to consider.

Comment: `h.update(line.chomp.scan(/(...)(.*)/).to_h)` seems a little labored. How about `h[line.slice!(0,3)] = line`?

Comment: @Jordan, Thanks. That's much improved. I'll make the change. Please be sure to leave your comment so that readers will know what I had originally.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = File.open("textfile.txt").read.split("\n")
hsh = {}
lines.each do |line|
  next if line == ""
  hsh[line[0..2]] = line[3..-1]
end
```

using your method of slowly nibbling at the file

```
f = File.open("textfile.txt")
hsh = {}
loop do
  x = f.gets
  break unless x
  hsh[x[0..2]] = x[3..-1]
end
```

Comment: Don't do this: `File.open("textfile.txt").read.split("\n")`. This will read the entire file into memory at once. Do this: `File.open("textfile.txt").each_line do ...`.

Comment: You seem defensive. I'm sorry about that. You're right that "don't do this" sounds dogmatic. The reasons to prefer `each_line` (especially over `read.split`—if you don't care about memory, there's `String#lines`) are beyond the scope of a comment, but I could have worded it better. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

Sample data:

```
[zatcsv]$ cat foo.txt 
TOK UPDATE DATE SHOT TIME AUXHEAT PHASE STATE PGASA PGASZ BGASA BGASZ BGASA2 BGASZ2 PIMPA
PIMPZ PELLET RGEO RMAG AMIN SEPLIM XPLIM KAPPA DELTA INDENT AREA VOL CONFIG IGRADB WALMAT DIVMAT LIMMAT EVAP 
BT IP VSURF Q95 BEPMHD BETMHD BEPDIA NEL DNELDT ZEFF PRAD POHM ENBI PINJ BSOURCE PINJ2 BSOURCE2 COCTR PNBI ECHFREQ 
ECHMODE ECHLOC PECH ICFREQ ICSCHEME ICANTEN PICRH LHFREQ LHNPAR PLH IBWFREQ PIBW TE0 TI0 WFANI WFICRH MEFF ISEQ WTH WTOT
JET 20031201 20001006 53521 1.000E+01 NBIC HSELM TRANS 2.000E+00 1.000E+00 2 1 0 0 1.658E+01 8.152E+00 NONE 2.888E+00 
HEEH OIJ OIJJ 3.047E+00 9.807E-01 2.924E-02 7.304E-02 1.572E+00 1.781E-01 0.000E+00 4.572E+00 8.161E+01 LSN 1 IN/
2.000E+06 1.013E-01 6.001E+00 1.053E+00 9.252E-01 1.128E+00 3.106E+19 3.106E+19 6.612E+00 4.515E+06 5.122E+04 1.000E+05 1.466E+07
771706 0.000E+00 652114 1.000E+00 1.420E+07 -9.999E-09 NONE NONE 0.000E+00 5.100E+07 HMIN MONOPOLE 4.027E+06 3.700E+09 1.840E+00
2.000E+06 -9.999E-09 0.000E+00 9.295E+03 1.373E+04 6.913E-01 7.319E+05 2.000E+00 NONE 3.715E+06 5.381E+06 1.282E+06 1.297E+07 1.210E+07
```

something like this will do it for you :

```
[za csv]$cat text_to_hash.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

file_dir = "/dir/to_folder/foo.txt"

 thehash = Hash.new

line = File.read(file_dir).each_line do |line|

  thehash[ key = line.slice(0..2)] = val = line.slice(3..-1)

  thehash.each { |k , val| puts " Key: #{key} Value:  #{val}"} 

end
```

Outputs:

```
[za csv]$ ./text_to_hash.rb
 Key: TOK Value:   UPDATE DATE SHOT TIME AUXHEAT PHASE STATE PGASA PGASZ BGASA BGASZ BGASA2 BGASZ2 PIMPA
 Key: PIM Value:  PZ PELLET RGEO RMAG AMIN SEPLIM XPLIM KAPPA DELTA INDENT AREA VOL CONFIG IGRADB WALMAT DIVMAT LIMMAT EVAP
 Key: ECH Value:  MODE ECHLOC PECH ICFREQ ICSCHEME ICANTEN PICRH LHFREQ LHNPAR PLH IBWFREQ PIBW TE0 TI0 WFANI WFICRH MEFF ISEQ WTH WTOT
 Key: JET Value:   20031201 20001006 53521 1.000E+01 NBIC HSELM TRANS 2.000E+00 1.000E+00 2 1 0 0 1.658E+01 8.152E+00 NONE 2.888E+00 
 Key: HEE Value:  H OIJ OIJJ 3.047E+00 9.807E-01 2.924E-02 7.304E-02 1.572E+00 1.781E-01 0.000E+00 4.572E+00 8.161E+01 LSN 1 IN/
 Key: 2.0 Value:  00E+06 1.013E-01 6.001E+00 1.053E+00 9.252E-01 1.128E+00 3.106E+19 3.106E+19 6.612E+00 4.515E+06 5.122E+04 1.000E+05 1.466E+07
 Key: 771 Value:  706 0.000E+00 652114 1.000E+00 1.420E+07 -9.999E-09 NONE NONE 0.000E+00 5.100E+07 HMIN MONOPOLE 4.027E+06 3.700E+09 1.840E+00
 Key: 2.0 Value:  00E+06 -9.999E-09 0.000E+00 9.295E+03 1.373E+04 6.913E-01 7.319E+05 2.000E+00 NONE 3.715E+06 5.381E+06 1.282E+06 1.297E+07 1.210E+07
 Key: 4.4 Value:  45E-01 2.194E-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing @Cary's sample file...

```
text = <<_
Now is the
time for all
good Rubiests
to come to the
aid of their
bowling team.
_

FName = 'temp'

File.write(FName, text)
```

Now the file exists. Convert it to a 2 dimensional array. This array is trivially converted to a hash

```
File.foreach(FName).map{|x| [x.slice!(0,3), x]}.to_h

=> {"Now"=>" is the\n", "tim"=>"e for all\n", "goo"=>"d Rubiests\n", "to "=>"come to the\n", "aid"=>" of their\n", "bow"=>"ling team.\n"}
```